# Mismatch between coordinates systems when converting from x, y -> lat long

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

***UPDATE THIS HAS BEEN RESOLVED, THE ISSUES WERE RELATED TO THE WRONG CONVERSION OF NDSFutility JS Code into Java***

---

I have a building's footprint which I extract from an IFC file:

https://www.iso.org/standard/51622.html.

IFC captures building geometries for buildings with a reference longitude and latitude. The building geometry is defined using a system of relative placements, and definitions of Polylines, etc. (although it supports multiple geometric representations of building geometries).

I want to convert a 2D representation of some of this geometry (walls) into geospatial data.

I have extracted the geometry (here as a list of points):

```
{"geometry":{"paths":[[[-2.58407192806819, -3.28072887478926], [7.715928071931811, -3.28072887478926]] ,[[-2.6840719280682, -9.080728874789271], [-2.6840719280682, -0.2807288747892702]] ,[[-13.184071928068201, -0.28072887478923203], [-13.184071928068201, -9.080728874789234]] ,[[7.7159280719318, -0.180728874789299], [-13.284071928068201, -0.180728874789299]] ,[[7.8159280719318005, -9.0807288747893], [7.8159280719318005, -0.08072887478929935]] ,[[-13.284071928068201, -9.180728874789231], [7.915928071931798, -9.180728874789231]]]}}
```

And I have extracted the models longitude and latitude, here represented as a wkt point POINT (-71.05977630611112 42.358428955). I want to convert the geometry to longitude and latitudes format using the given ref longitude and latitude in the IFC file so that I can display the selected 2D geometry on a map.

To do this I found this code and converted it to Java - http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/utility/NDSFutility.js

I ran the code and converted each point based on the reference longitude and latitude of the file. I converted it to WSG84. It seems that the geometries do not match though, and seem to be slightly off. Here is the wkt output:

```
MULTILINESTRING ((-71.05984749254343 42.358376156434254, -71.05972247208217 42.358376156434254), (-71.0599191062312 42.35832304098344, -71.0599191062312 42.35840226402872), (-71.05993974039522 42.35830773653188, -71.05993974039522 42.35822851348528), (-71.05968484441314 42.35849679152554, -71.05993974087394 42.35849679152554), (-71.05979165804781 42.3584175684816, -71.05979165804781 42.35849859204928), (-71.06004898161066 42.358226712961496, -71.05979165833584 42.358226712961496))
```

My code is directly mapped from the JS, so I am trying to figure out where the error is.

Comment: Your ESRI json claims that data are already in EPSG:3857 `"spatialReference":{"wkid":3857}}}` but at the place around -2.58407192806819, -3.28072887478926 there are no buildings because it is just a few meters away from the Null Island https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island. There is obviously something wrong with your source data.

Comment: The source data is generated from a cartesian coordinate system. Should it matter which spatialReference I use there? I can change that value and the coordinates still render correctly. Perhaps I am missing something in the conversion process related to the coordinate system used? I thought I should be able to simply convert the xy -> ll using the equivalent xy2ll function in ndsf? Its not that the points are in the wrong location...they roughly are after the conversion, the problem is that they are all slightly offset.

Comment: Conversion from one coordinate system into another requires 1) the source coordinates 2) correct knowledge about in which coordinate system the source coordinates are expressed, and 3) the target coordinate system. In your case it feels like 2) is unknown.

Comment: The source coordinates of the geometry are expressed using a euclidean geometry. I have one longitude and latitude for that geometry (which is extracted from an IFC file). I am using that longitude and latitude to convert the x, y coordinates of the geometry into longitude and latitude for each point. What you are saying is that I need to know what the longitude and latitude are expressed in before doing any conversion? I assumed they were WGS84...the reference longitude/latitude in the original IFC file is 42°21'30"344238 and -71°-3'-35"-194702.

Comment: Please add all that information into the body of your question. Do you mean that if the starting point of your geometry is `-2.58407192806819, -3.28072887478926` then you add into it some offset that you take from IFC file (btw. what is is, could you link a specification?) and as a next step you do a conversion with javascript?

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully it makes more sense now?

Comment: Yes, a little bit. I do not still totally understand what you do for the first point `-2.58407192806819, -3.28072887478926` with `42°21'30"344238 and -71°-3'-35"-194702` for getting the result `-71.3352657249399 42.21298162387592`.

Comment: There is a function in the NDSF JS called translate_coordinates(int trans_option, double[] d) which transforms the coordinate based on a specific origin (in this case, the reference longitude and latitude in the IFC file). I generate this by just compressing the number into a double. So 42°21'30"344238 becomes 42.2130344238

Comment: _"So 42°21'30"344238 becomes 42.2130344238"_ That's not how lat/long coordinates work.  42°21'30" is 42 degrees, 21 minutes, 30 seconds. It's not 42.2130 degrees, it's closer to 42.35 degrees. Read this: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/motion1/tc_units.html.

Comment: Ahhh, well that is very good to know. I got bad information in that case. Can you point me to a method for doing that conversion? I see a few with degrees, minutes and seconds, but I do not see any with sexagesimal values.

Comment: Found this - https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=IPARCOS-master/app/src/main/java/farom/iparcos/catalog/Coordinates.java Will try and see how it goes!

Comment: I suggest to put up a local transverse mercator coordinate system with the reference point (in decimal degrees) as origin and meters as units.. Using GDAL, you can transform the data from this CRS to any well-known CRS. Note that EPSG:3857 does not use real world meters as units.

Comment: Okay, I updated the code to fix the issue mentioned by Dan C. As I suspected, this has no bearing on the transformation I am using to convert the coordinates. I am still getting a mismatch between the positioning of the geometry in the Cartesian coordinate system and the geospatial. I will edit the original question to show the results now.

Comment: @AndreJ, so if I understand you correctly, in your opinion the NDFSutility JS is not a reliable method for converting between a Cartesian coordinate system and geospatial?

Comment: Hi all, I have managed to fix the problem. There were two errors that had crept into my code when I had converted the JS into Java. It is working now. Many thanks all of you for your help. Should I leave this post for others, or can I delete it?

Comment: Please self-answer your question, for the benefit of future visitors. Another solution I had in mind was FreeCAD, which can read IFC, and has GDAL support (but I have not tested it yet).